"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=6.0.35.0,Culture=neutral"
I get an error running the selected code generator:

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=6.0.35.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040)


Hi Sarthak, please share your .csproj file, we need to check the packages version.

One more thing, did you copy/download the project from some where ? If yes, please try to delete bin, obj and .vs folders.

Where to share it?

Hi @Sarthak, you can edit the post.
